# Can I determine whether clicking a link successfully opened a new window/tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, href

I have an `<input>` element inside an `<a>` element, meaning IE8 ignores the `<a>` element's href attribute when clicked.  It works fine on all other browsers.  *Is there a way to determine whether a new tab/window opened?*  I can then give the user a normal/ugly link to click if it didn't work.

Code example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://somelink.com"><input type="button" class="standard_button_styling" /></a>
```

What I've tried:

1. Remove the `<input>` tag and style the `<a>` tag: I had trouble making it look just like my other buttons (maybe due to native browser styling) and I don't want it to look worse for everyone to fix a problem with only IE8.
2. Trigger link with JavaScript window.open(): This doesn't send the referer_url in IE, and the somelink.com in my example relies on it.  So I need to have the user click a normal link.
3. Browser detection: I could just look for IE8 and provide a different response for IE8, but browser detection instead of feature detection is regarded as bad practice and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `<button>` instead of `<input>` but I am not sure if this will solve the problem. 
 Or just use `<form>`.

```
<form method="get" target="_blank" action="yourlink">
    <input type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
```

Comment: Turning it into a button doesn't work - but turning it into a form works.  Thanks!